# how to show uploaded image in mail to admin uploaded through form

Tags: magento2

hello everyone I want shows the uploaded image of the form in the mail to admin in mail image name is coming but I want to show the image

Answer (score 0):

Image Form id `field_name`

> Form.php

```
$fieldset->addType('productimage', '\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Renderer\Image');
$fieldset->addField('field_name', 'productimage', array(           
   'label'     => __('Image')));
```

> Image.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Renderer;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{                   
       private $_storeManager;
   /**
    * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
    * @param array $data
    */
   public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, 
StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
   {
       $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
    /**
     * get category name
     * @param  DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        // here you can write your code.
        $html = '';

        if ($this->getValue()) 
        {
            $html = $this->getMediaImageHtml($this->getValue());
        } 
        return $html;
    }
    public function getMediaImageHtml($imageName)
    {
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
    );
        $Image = $this->getValue(); 
        $html = "<img src='".$mediaDirectory.$Image."' height='250px' width='250px'>";        
        return $html;
    }
}
```