# Magento 2: Upload image without Ui component

Tags: magento2, image, image-upload, file-upload

how can I upload an image by this way, please help me, thank you
[image]

```
     $fieldset->addField(
        'image_field_name',
        'image',
        [
            'name'        => 'image_field_name',
            'label'       => __('Image field Label'),
            'title'       => __('Image field Label'),
        ]
    );
```

Comment: try following link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/275815/60921